# Numpy vectorized summation with variable number of factors

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I am currently computing a function that contains a summation over an index. The index is between 0 and the integer part of T; ideally I would like to be able to compute this summation quickly for several values of T. 
In a real-life case, most of the values of T are small, but a small percentage can be one or two orders of magnitude larger than the average.

What I am doing now is:
1) I define the vector T, e.g. (my real-life data have a much larger number of entries, it is just to give an idea):

```
import numpy as np 
T = np.random.exponential(5, 10)
```

2) I create a matrix containing the factors between 0 and int(T), and then zeroes:

```
n = int(T.max())
j = ((np.arange(n) < T[:,np.newaxis])*np.arange(1,n+1)).astype(int).transpose()
print(j)
```

> [[ 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1]
>    [ 2  0  2  2  2  0  2  0  2  2]
>    [ 0  0  3  0  3  0  3  0  3  3]
>    [ 0  0  4  0  4  0  0  0  4  4]
>    [ 0  0  5  0  5  0  0  0  5  5]
>    [ 0  0  6  0  6  0  0  0  6  6]
>    [ 0  0  7  0  7  0  0  0  0  7]
>    [ 0  0  8  0  8  0  0  0  0  8]
>    [ 0  0  9  0  9  0  0  0  0  9]
>    [ 0  0  0  0 10  0  0  0  0 10]
>    [ 0  0  0  0 11  0  0  0  0  0]
>    [ 0  0  0  0 12  0  0  0  0  0]]

3) I generate the single elements of the summation, using a mask to avoid applying the function to the elements that are zero:

```
A =  np.log(1 + (1 + j) * 5)* (j>0)
```

4) I sum along the columns:

```
A.sum(axis=0)
```

Obtaining:
array([  5.170484  ,   2.39789527,  29.96464821,   5.170484  ,
        42.29052851,   2.39789527,   8.21500643,   2.39789527,
        18.49060911,  33.9899999 ])

Is there a fastest/better way to vectorize that? I have the feeling that it is very slow due to the large amount of zeroes that do not contribute to the sum, but since I am a beginner with NumPy I couldn't figure out a better way of writing it.

EDIT: in my actual problem, the function applied to j depends also on a second parameter tau (in a vector of the same size of T). So the items contained in every column are not the same.

Comment: Could you add some representative sample case involving the `tau` to explain your EDIT in a bit more detailed manner? Also, for future posts, please use a sample case that is representative of the actual case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your `j`, for each column it has numbers going from `1` to `N`, where `N` is being decided based on each `T` element. Then, you are summing along each column, which is the same as summing until `N` because rest of the elements are zeros anyway. Those summed values could be calculated with [`np.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and those `N` values that are basically the limits of each column in `j` could be directly calculated from `T`. These `N` values are then used as indices to index into the `cumsum-ed` values to give us the final output.

This should be pretty fast and memory efficient, given that `cumsum` is the only computation done and that too on a 1D array, as compared to the summation done in the original approach on a 2D array along each column. Thus, we have a vectorized approach like so -

```
n = int(T.max())
vals = (np.log(1 + (1 + np.arange(1,n+1)) * 5)).cumsum()
out = vals[(T.astype(int)).clip(max=n-1)]
```

In terms of memory usage, we are generating three variables -

```
n    : Scalar
vals : 1D array of n elements 
out  : 1D array of T.size elements (this is the output anyway)
```

Runtime test and verify output -

```
In [5]: def original_app(T):
   ...:     n = int(T.max())
   ...:     j = ((np.arange(n) < T[:,None])*np.arange(1,n+1)).astype(int).transpose()
   ...:     A =  np.log(1 + (1 + j) * 5)* (j>0) 
   ...:     return A.sum(axis=0)
   ...: 
   ...: def vectorized_app(T):
   ...:     n = int(T.max())
   ...:     vals = (np.log(1 + (1 + np.arange(1,n+1)) * 5)).cumsum()
   ...:     return vals[(T.astype(int)).clip(max=n-1)]
   ...: 

In [6]: # Input array
   ...: T = np.random.exponential(5, 10000)

In [7]: %timeit original_app(T)
100 loops, best of 3: 9.62 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit vectorized_app(T)
10000 loops, best of 3: 50.1 µs per loop

In [9]: np.allclose(original_app(T),vectorized_app(T)) # Verify outputs
Out[9]: True
```

Comment: Nice, it looks like it is much faster  but I am not sure I understand why. What is cumsum doing? Is the cumulative sum much faster than the sum?

Comment: @PiZed Added few comments on it, check it out.